# How to make a JS that put html code on a page

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make a .js file that will store it seft some html tables and put the contents on the page that include .js file

how i can do that? this could replace some iframes roles.

Comment: The problem is, that this question is too generic. Meaning that you should explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<p>Some html code</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `innerHTML` tag of Javascript.

Like this:-

```
 document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li></ol>';
```

Comment: On a side note **innerHTML** is not accessable for all types of tags when using IE.